# What assumptions should code make about CPU memory model, and how should such assumptions be documented?

Tags: .net, multithreading, memory-barriers, memory-model

From what I've read, Intel processor architectures enforce a stronger memory model than .net implementations are required to provide.  To what extent is it proper for code to make use of the guarantees which Intel processors make, or to what extent should code add memory barriers which would not be required for an Intel implementation, in case the code gets migrated to a platform with a weaker memory model?  Would it be appropriate to define a static class with methods to e.g. "perform memory barrier if using weak memory model", and require that code be linked with either a "strong model" or "weak model" version of that library as appropriate?  Alternatively, could Reflection be used to generate such a static class at program startup, in such a way that the JIT compiler could, when using a strong model, "inline-expand" the "memory barrier if weak" instructions to nothing (i.e. omit them entirely from the JITted code)?

If I had my druthers, .net would provide a variation of the `MemoryLock` class with some semi-lock operations which would require that all threads which hold a semi-lock would be required to abide by that semi-lock's memory model.  In a system with a very strong memory model, the semi-locks would do nothing.  In a system with a very weak memory model, any thread wishing to enter a semi-lock which already had another thread in it would have to wait until either the first thread had exit, or it could get scheduled with the CPU or core (based upon the model specified by the semi-lock) that the first thread was using.  Note that unlike a normal lock, a `MemoryLock` could never deadlock since any combination of conflicting lock requirements could be resolved by scheduling all threads to run on the same CPU, and the system could release any `MemoryLock` held by a thread which dies (since the purpose of the `MemoryLock` would be to protect resources from being accessed in ways that would violate the memory model, and a dead thread can of course make no such access).

Of course, such a thing doesn't exist as of .net 4.0; given that, what is the best way to handle the situation that does exist?  Migrating code which is designed for a stronger memory model to a system with a weaker model, in the absence of some means to enforce the stronger model, would be a recipe for disaster, but adding lots of `Lock` or `MemoryBarrier` calls which would be unnecessary for the code's original target platform doesn't seem very appealing.  The only way I know of for code to force a strong memory model would be to have each thread set its CPU affinity.  If there were a way to set a process option so .net would only use one core at a time, that might be useful (especially if it meant that the JIT could replace bus-locking interlocked operations with faster non-bus-locking equivalents), but the only means I know of setting CPU affinity would limit a program to using a particular selected CPU for all its threads, even if that CPU was heavily loaded by other applications and some other CPU was sitting idle.

**Addendum**

Consider the following code:

```
// Thread 1 -- Assume that at start SharedPerson points to a Person "Smiley", "George"
  var newPerson = new Person();
  newPerson.LastName = "Simpson";
  newPerson.FirstName = "Bart";
  // MaybeMemoryBarrier1
  SharedPerson = newPerson;

// Thread 2
  var wasPerson = SharedPerson;
  // MaybeMemoryBarrier2
  var wasLastName = wasPerson.FirstName;
  var WasFirstName = wasPerson.LastName;
```

By my understanding, even in the absence of memory barriers, code running on an Intel processor will guarantee that writes will not be resequenced; consequently, in Thread 2, the person which is read will either be "Smiley", "George" or "Simpson", "Bart".  The .net memory model, however, is weaker than that, and a .net program could find itself running on a processor where Thread 2 might see an incomplete object (since the write to `SharedPerson` could occur before the write to `newPerson.FirstName`).  Adding a memory barrier at `MaybeMemoryBarrier1` would avoid that danger, but memory barriers have a performance cost whether or not they're actually needed.

I don't think the minimal-required .net memory model is so weak as to require `MaybeMemoryBarrier2` in cases where Thread 2 is guaranteed never to have accessed the object referred to by `SharedPerson` prior to reading `SharedPerson` itself (as would be the case in the above code, since the new instance doesn't get exposed to any outside code before it's stored in `SharedPerson`).  On the other hand, suppose the situation were changed slightly, so `Thread 2` created a `JobInfo` record, which it then placed in a queue for `Thread 1` (assuming all necessary locks and memory barriers for the queue itself); subsequent to that, the processors do:

```
// Thread 1
  var newJob = JobQueue.GetJob(); // Gets JobInfo that was written by Thread2
  newJob.StartTime = DateTime.Now(); // Eight-byte struct might straddle cache line
                                     // Will never be changed once written
  // MaybeMemoryBarrier1
  CurrentJob = newJob;

// Thread 2
  var wasJob = CurrentJob;
  // MaybeMemoryBarrier2
  var wasStartTime = CurrentJob.StartTime();
```

If Thread 1 has a memory barrier, but Thread 2 does not, is there any guarantee that when Thread 2 sees the `JobInfo` record it created appear in `CurrentJob`, it will correctly read its `StartTime` field (and won't either see a cached or partially cached value left over from the time `Thread 2` was manipulating that object?

Comment: This is a very broad question- can you provide a specific example of where the a .NET application would reliably work correctly on an Intel platform and fail (reliably or otherwise) on another platform?  I am not sure that there are such cases, but if there are, I'd be interested in seeing one.  My expectation would be that you will have basically zero performance improvement by micro-optimizing for the architecture's memory model (over and above the optimizations that JIT would already do for whatever the current architecture is).

Comment: @ChrisShain: Example added.  My concern is actually less about performance than correctness (or, to be more precise, being able to ensure correctness on machines with lose architectures, without seriously dogging the performance on tight ones.  Throwing memory barriers between all memory accesses will achieve correctness on any memory model, but could cause an order-of-magnitude slowdown.

Comment: Is there anything explicitly saying the CLR itself can't reorder reads and writes (except for the obvious limitations) if there's nothing explicitly preventing it (ie: no memory barriers)?

Comment: My advice to you is to always protect shared/passed objects between threads with barriers. Otherwise even on x86/x64 unless you mark things volatile the generated code could be optimized to where you'd get the wrong behavior.

Comment: @RobinCaron: Certainly if threads are actively passing data, memory barriers would seem appropriate.  My concern was largely with situations where threading issues might cause what should be "immutable" data to not appear as immutable.  For example, if two threads might simultaneously try to store references to logically-equivalent logically-immutable objects into the same storage location, they could use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` to ensure one wins, but it shouldn't matter if both stores happen separately.  On the other hand, if threading issues mean that some threads might not...

Comment: ...perceive the objects as equivalent, having both stores occur could be bad.  Also, unless there is some way to cause a runtime library to randomize memory sequencing to the maximum extent allowed by the standard (even beyond what the CPU would generally do), validating code to ensure that there aren't any potentially-dangerous situations could be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: You should write code against the .net memory model only; no stronger.

It is true that the x86 architecture has a stronger memory model than the one described by .net.

But even if you never plan to port your code to other platforms (e.g. ARM) you should not think in terms of the x86 memory model. Because your compiler and the JITer are free to do optimizations that break the x86 model. So you are not safe, even on an Intel CPU.

For instance, the JIT could decide to avoid the newPerson local variable totally in your example, which would be equivalent to this code:

```
SharedPerson = new Person();
SharedPerson.LastName = "Simpson";
SharedPerson.FirstName = "Bart";
```

Do you see how broken this is? Even with a previously initialized SharedPerson, thread 2 can see FirstName and LastName == null (if it reads before they are set)! This optimization is perfectly legal and doesn't change the single-threaded behavior.

Without proper synchronization, the hardware *and the runtime* are free to introduce/eliminate/reorder memory writes and reads as they please, as long as the single-threaded behavior doesn't change.

To atomically publish a reference to other threads, you should use a volatile write. If SharedPerson is volatile your code is fine (no need for additional explicit memory barriers). And note that on x86 a volatile write is just a regular write, so it comes 'for free': the runtime doesn't add any instruction. But it does prohibit optimizations by the .net runtime (the example above becomes illegal because no previous memory operation can move after a volatile write. So .LastName and .FirstName *must* be assigned before the volatile write happens).

Comment: I can see your point about the potential for compiler reordering, though it would seem unfortunate if the only way to prevent such compiler optimization would be to add a memory barrier, since memory barriers can have a significant run-time cost *even [especially] in cases where they're unnecessary*.

Comment: I've adressed this in my reply. You can prevent those optimizations by using a volatile SharedPerson. A volatile field has _zero_ overhead on x86-x64, the generated native code is the same as a regular field.

Comment: I thought that a volatile field declaration in C# would not only prevent reordering, but also cause the compiler to add memory barriers to reads and writes, since there are times when memory barriers are needed, even under the x86 memory model.

Comment: It is my understanding that the volatile semantics have been modeled after the x86 architecture. Unlike Java that now enforces a full memory barrier on volatile access, .net only provides acquire semantics on reads and release on writes. Those half-fences mean that a volatile read may move up past a previous volatile write. If this is important in your case, you should manually add a full memory barrier in between. On other architectures with weaker memory models (e.g. Itanium), volatile access need a different instruction than a regular access.

Comment: You may want to read this article: [The C# memory model in theory and practice, part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883956.aspx), especially the section "C# Memory Model Implementation on the x86-x64". I quote: "One interesting piece of trivia is that the C# volatile semantics closely match the hardware reordering guarantees made by x86-x64 hardware. As a result, reads and writes of volatile fields require no special instructions on the x86: Ordinary reads and writes (for example, using the MOV instruction) are sufficient".

Comment: Just digging this out to say that Java's memory model regarding volatile read/write is not full memory barrier, it's acquire/release.  So, it's not enough to just read or to just write using a volatile field, you must write then read the same field for synchronization.  Essentially, the same as in ECMA .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that your understanding is correct.  The .NET memory model does seem to allow reordering of stores, that is, on some nonexistant CPU with an extremely weak memory model, SharedPerson could be stored by thread1 before it's `FirstName` and `LastName` members are stored, resulting in "Bart"/null or null/"Simpson", or even null/null.  But I do not believe that it is possible for a weak memory model to result in *inconsistent writes* ("George"/"Simpson") in your example, given that thread2 creates a local reference to `SharedPerson` and reads from that, while thread1 is performing an atomic replacement of `SharedPerson` with a new instance.

The [CLI spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) states:

> A conforming CLI shall guarantee that read and write access to
>   properly aligned memory locations no larger than the native word size
>   (the size of type native int) is atomic (see §12.6.2) when all the
>   write accesses to a location are the same size

That said, as far as I know no such memory model exists on any supported platform, and Chris Brumme's blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/05/17/51445.aspx) suggests similar.

Comment: The inconsistent appearance would occur under the scenario that some time before any of the indicated code for either thread had run, some code on Thread 2 had read the object to which `SharedPerson` would eventually refer (so `Smiley, George` was in that thread's cache, possibly straddling a cache-line boundary), and some time after that read one of the cache lines holding part of that instance got invalidated (so `George` was still cached, but `Smiley` wasn't).  If `SharedName` refers to an object instance which had previously been used on Thread 2, the CPU would only have to...

Comment: ...read the portion of the object which was no longer cached.  As I noted, this danger can be avoided by not recycling objects.  On the other hand, it does seem somewhat icky that code like what appears in `Thread 2` would be dependent upon `SharedPerson` not pointing to a recycled object.  Although recycling generally requires locks, the locks required for recycling would not necessarily prevent the above problem.

Comment: Also, even if no existing implementations of .net would reorder writes, any code which assumes that writes will not get reordered would seem liable to break on any implementation of .net which does something that implementations are explicitly permitted to do.

Comment: No, here you are definitely wrong.  Thread2, upon executing `var wasPerson = SharedPerson;`, is either going to execute a read of SharedPerson from main memory or not (if SharedPerson is already cached).  Either way, the value of the ***original instance*** of SharedPerson doesn't change in your example.  All that happens is that sometime when (or after) thread1 executes `SharedPerson = newPerson;`, the value of the reference in main memory is changed to point at a new instance (at a different memory location, again in main memory).  That is an atomic operation.

Comment: ... continued from above...  When thread2 reads SharedPerson from main memory, it either gets the original SharedPerson instance (with references to the strings "George" "Smiley"), or the new instance (whose references may or may not be set to "Bart" "Simpson", but are *never* set to "George" "Smiley").  I think that you are operating under an assumption that `var wasPerson = SharedPerson;` creates a variable whose value will be updated when `SharedPerson` is changed, and that isn't the case.

Comment: You're right--my example in the comments was flawed.  Suppose the shared field points to a `JobInfo` record which is supposed to supply information about the job currently being performed by Thread 1.  Thread 2 generates a `JobInfo` record and places it in a queue; Thread 1 some time later reads it from the queue, updates some fields (e.g. `JobStartTime`, `RemoteServerTaskID`) within that record, performs a memory barrier, and then sets a shared field `CurrentJob` to point to it.  Would a weak memory model guarantee that if Thread 2 sees the update to `CurrentJob` it will also see...

Comment: ...the field updates that were performed by Thread 1, whether or not Thread 2 has a memory barrier of its own (and won't try to use cached values from the last time it had accessed that object)?

Comment: That's where I am not sure- theoretically a very weak memory model might allow thread1 to reorder the updates to the job before it is set to CurrentJob, but now we are talking about an entirely theoretical situation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12622/discussion-between-supercat-and-chris-shain)